# Httpcontext.session is null in Provider hosted app

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a on premise provider hosted app and when i publish the web part on my local IIS server and uploading the app file to app catalogue and trying to access the default page, I am getting HttpContext.session as null on the default.aspx page. My app is working fine if i add simple html page with static text. Can anyone guide me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Another website (simple .NET web) on your Server IIS is OK?

Comment: Could you check and confirm whether session is enabled in SharePoint. You can use command Get-SPSessionStateService in sharepoint management shell as administrator.